# How to securely serve files from IIS using custom auth?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I'm trying to securely serve images/video from my asp.net application and struggling to find an efficient way of doing that.

I'm using WebAPI with custom auth. User receives a token on login and then supplies it with every request inside Authorization http header. This way I can make sure that only logged in users can access secured API functions.

However, IIS also serves images and videos for those users and they have to be secured as well. Also users will have different rights to access those files.

I tried few approaches:

- I can create a custom managed handler that will be serving these files after checking `Authorization` header, but I don't think it's efficient, as IIS would do a much better job at serving the files, utilising caching and so on.
- I tried creating and registering new `HttpModule`, that would check the header in `BeginRequest` and it works fine even with virtual directories. 
  However, I use Applications to separate App Pools for serving files and API. If files are stored in child Application (not virtual folder), then request is not passing via my HttpModule (I could prob. register one in every app but that complicates things a lot as I won't be able to use parent app for checking token in one place)

Is there a way to analyse headers in parent app when files are requested from child applications?

Am I completely missing the point and there is an easier way to secure serving of static files with IIS when using custom authentication? I don't have to pass tokens via custom header. If needed I can do it via cookies or even url param (ssl only of course).

Many thanks !